# Books/Material for RF transmitter/receiver design

Tags: rf, wireless, transmitter, receiver

I am doing my thesis for my BSc in EE. Due to a lack of equipped laboratories in my universities, I cannot do a project in microwave-integrated circuits, as I would have preferred. I am therefore looking to build a transmitter and emitter in lower frequencies, say the MF band. Most of my RF books deal with much higher frequencies. What reading material do you recommend for my case?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a lot worse than the The ARRL Handbook for Radio Communications, and the older editions can be had very cheaply second hand.